# Tightly pack a grid of list items in HTML

Tags: html, css, grid, vertical-alignment

For part of a site I'm making, I'm looking to have a grid of square objects, and have them pack together tightly so there's no spaces.

Here is what I have made:
[image: Not packed very well]

But here's what I want it to look like:
[image: Packed perfectly]

So far I've only been doing this by padding and adding margins, and then by vertically aligning each list item. But I want it to go one step further than vertical alignment, I want each item to fit directly underneath the one above it.

I'm sure there's a very different, better approach than the one I've taken, which would be great too!

Here's what I have done:

HTML:

```
 <header class="results">
        <ul class="container">
            <li>
                <a id="name">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="name">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="name">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="name">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="name">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="name">Temp</a>
                <a id="position">Temp</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.page {
  background: #fff;
}
header.results {
  max-width: 100%;
}
header.results .container {
  padding: 1em 0 2em;
  margin: 0px auto 3px;
  line-height: 1;
}
header.results .container li {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em 2em 0.75em;
  margin: 0px auto 3px;
  background: rgb(240,240,240);
  vertical-align: top;
}
header.results .container li #name {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
header.results .container li #position {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 250;
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

Comment: Using em in layouts is tricky - em adjusts not only to the containing element, but also to the PARENT of the containing element. This could be the issue in your setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not supporting older browsers (IE 8 & 9), you could implement this with CSS columns, as shown [here.](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout)

For full browser support, I'd go with the [jQuery masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).